# Detect file change in PHP without polling

Tags: php, filesystems, inotify

I'm trying to detect when a particular file is modified without polling the contents of the file looking for changes.

The server runs Mac OS X, so `inotify` is not available. My server allows for the use of `exec()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As an alternative, you could check the `filemtime` to get the last time a file was modified, and if it changed since its last call, you can assume the file changed.

Comment: You could hash the file at points in time to see if it's changed. However, `filemtime` is significantly less cpu-expensive.

Comment: php.net mentions that the output of filemtime gets cached, and that if a single script is using filemtime on a single file multiple times, clearstatcache() should be called, however it reduces performance.

Comment: *every programming statement* reduces performance. who cares?

Comment: @rambocoder tell us what software you write so that we could avoid it.

Comment: filemtime appears to return the time of the last file modification in seconds (On OS X, anyway), which means if the file is modified twice in the same second, the second modification is missed, which makes it unsuitable for files which are modified frequently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime). You can poll it every so often and it's much easier than looking for changes in the file itself.